# Access object current during creation possible?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to access the current object during creation in javascript?

Example:

```
var data = {x: 1, z:x}
```

OR

```
var data = {x: 1, z: data.x}
```

This code does acutally **not** work but i wonder if this is possible somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a constructor function

Comment: @Hacketo: but that's no more equivalent to the object literal (prototype inheritance, re-constructability etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using constructor function

```
var data = function() {
    if ( !(this instanceof data ) ) {
        return new data();
    }

    this.y = 3;
    this.x = this.y;
}

var obj = new data()
```

EDIT: Better practice

Comment: That was quick! Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your edit: Is this then a singleton?

Comment: @Freddi: No, it just lets you call `data` without `new`. I.e. if you call `data()`, it will internally call `return new data();`.